# How does one write a suffix on double words?

Tags: suffixes

I was wondering how I should write words like "control structureless". Should you keep the space between the words, concatenate them or use a hyphen?

In my native language, Dutch, we would write "controlestructuurloos", so you would concatenate, but I could imagine it's not supposed to be done like that in English.

EDIT: By "control structureless" I mean "without control structures".

Comment: Not exactly the route I was thinking of, "control structure" is one thing, a structure that is controlled.

Comment: Rewrite the sentence so it is in better English, as in "without structure controls."

Comment: As @pazzo says, a rewrite is better. You should only use "control-structureless" to be funny or if you are sure you''ll be understood in context. Even then it sounds awkward.

Comment: How would you say "there's no speed limit on this highway"? *The highway is speedlimitless*? Or *The highway has no speed limit*?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for

***control-structure-less*** thing

for best clarity, even though hyphenating suffixes isn't done in formal writing, but it seems this other version is accepted and published (see Google Books):

> [Artificial Reefs in Fisheries Management](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-L5nva1nXvsC&pg=PA138&dq=%22control%20structureless%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x6Q3VcG7CbG0sAS9q4DwBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22control%20structureless%22&f=false) - Page 138 Stephen A.
>   Bortone, ‎Frederico Pereira Brandini, ‎Gianna Fabi - 2011
>
> Unfortunately, the lack of concurrent surveys **at
>   control-structureless sites** after 1997 precluded any definite
>   inference on whether the deployment of reef balls in 2002, the
>   regional variations (both naturally induced or human-induced) of fish